# Stable distributions and equivalence of certain definitions

Tags: probability

There are several definitions of stable distributions. The most ubiquitous is
arguably that  if $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots $ are i.i.d. random variables with probability distribution $F $ then, $F $ is stable if
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i =_d aX+b $$
for some $a>0 $ and $b \in R. $

There are other definitions. In particular those based on convergence and domain of attractions. But, though those may be complicated, right now do not
concern me. While browsing the internet, more or less at random as a dutiful
probabilist should do, I came across this definition as well:

A random variable $Y $ is stable iff for any arbitrary constants $b_1 $ and $b_2, $ there exist constants $a $ and $b $ such that 
$$ b_1 Y_1 + b_2Y_2 =_d aY+b, $$
with $Y=_d Y_1 =_d Y_2. $

This definition is found in Uchaikin and Zolotarev, *Chance and Stability. Stable distributions and their applications* (1999), p. 43, formula 2.2.12.

I can see that the second definition can lead to the first one. . But I cannot see the way from the first  definition down  to the second since the first one uses positive norming costants only.

I wonder if anyone has seen this before and could help me see the equivalence between the definitions.

Thank you
Maurice

Comment: In the case where $b_1 $ and $b_2 $ are positive, I seem to go somewhere. If $X $ is stable then its characteristic function $\phi $ satisfies the following